# Need help fixing program with functions

Tags: c++

```
int smallest(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int smallest = x;
    if (y < smallest)
        smallest = y;
    if (z < smallest)
        smallest = z;
    return smallest;
}

void printmessage(int smallest)
{
    int w = 0;
    if(smallest < 0 || smallest >= 10)
        cout << "it is not possible to print the message in this case" << endl;
    else
    {
        for(w < 0 ||w > 10; w < smallest; w++)
            cout << "No" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

This just basically reads in 3 values and finds the smallest. The message "No" is printed out based on the smallest value. If it's 5, "no" will be printed out 5 times. Not sure how to fix the part where I declare the smallest in `printmessage`. Can somebody help me fix it?

Comment: `smallest(x,y,z)` can be replaced with `std::min({x,y,z})`.

Comment: What is `printmessage()` supposed to do?

Comment: print out a message based on the smallest integer

Comment: What message, though? We can't help you "fix it" if you don't specify what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The message "No" as many times as the smallest integer. If it's 5 times no will be printed out 5 times.

Comment: Your recent edit completely wrecks the question — it makes it incomprehensible.  There is no code left that is reading anything.  So, I've rolled back to the prior version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you just need to fix the first part of your `for` loop:

```
void printmessage(int smallnum) {
    if(smallnum < 0 || smallnum >= 10) {
        cout << "it is not possible to print the message in this case" << endl;
    } else {
        for(int w = 0; w < smallnum; w++) {
            cout << "No" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the change in the parameter name - right now, you already have a function called `smallest()`, so you shouldn't create a variable with this name, too, or you're going to get weird things happening. Same thing for your `smallest()` function itself - change the first line, `int smallest = x;` to `int smallnum = x` or similar, and change the references to it in the rest of your function.

And, as namfuak points out in the comments, change `printmessage(smallest);` to `printmessage(smallest(x, y, z));`, otherwise you're trying to pass the address of the function, instead of its result.

In a full working example:

```
#include <iostream>

void printmessage(int smallnum) {
    if(smallnum < 0 || smallnum >= 10) {
        std::cout << "it is not possible to print the message in this case"
                  << std::endl;
    } else {
        for(int w = 0; w < smallnum; ++w) {
            std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printmessage(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$ ./smallest
No
No
No
No
No
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$
```

Comment: I get |30|error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int, int, int)' to 'int' [-fpermissive]| on line 30 trying to put printmessage() into main. and |5|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void printmessage(int)' [-fpermissive]| declaring printmessage()

Comment: @John: You also have a function called `smallest`, change the name of the parameter in `printmessage()`, see edit.

Comment: @John If your code is the same as in the OP, you are trying to pass the function "smallest" as a parameter rather than passing the result, you should put in printmessage(smallest(x, y, z)), or assign the result to a variable and use the variable.

Comment: Thanks finally got! Forgot to add in variables for smallest.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(w < 0 ||w > 10; w < smallest; w++)
```

The first section of this is effectively meaningless, while the statement technically is executed the first statement in a for loop is colloquially for initializing and/or assigning loop control variables.  In your case,  you probably want to use this:

```
for(int w = 0; w < smallest; w++)
```

This will initialize the a variable "w" within the scope of the loop, rather than the scope of the function (so after the loop exits, "w" will be discarded).  Since you only need it within the loop, this should be what you are looking for.

If you want to check that w is also not less than 0 or greater than ten, you can use the following loop:

```
for(int w = 0; w < 0 || w > 10, w < smallest; w++)
```

You can also leave the initial w in the function scope if you need it later (or in other cases where you don't need a loop control variable) and have a blank statement in that space in the loop declaration instead:

```
for(; w < smallest; w++)
```